# How to troubleshoot and solve /var/www/html permissions problems?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, lamp, vsftpd

So, I am running Debian Stretch with a LAMP server and vsFTPd.  When ever I upload a new file or create a new file in the /var/www/html directory with a code editing program, I am unable to view the file/image/what-be-it, until I apply 777 permissions to the /var/www/html folder.  I know this is not the best solution but I have ran through several iterations of trying

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/www/mysite
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [my username]
```

and the similar with no luck.  How would I go about trouble shooting and eventually solving this issue so I do not need to putty into the server every time I upload some images or a new page to reset permissions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I would assume its a development question because I use the lamp server in my development process...